# eval() is not allowed

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, eval

I am using the WPAlchemy MetaBox PHP Class in my wordpress theme for some custom post types.
Problem appears when I run the Theme-Check:

```
WARNING: Found eval in the file inc/metaboxes/MediaAccess.php. eval() is not allowed.. 
Line 375: data = eval('(' + (data.indexOf('{') < 0 ? '{' + data + '}' : data) + ')');
```

I don't know why this is coming up, as line 375 is JavaScript enclosed in: CDATA

See below excerpt from MediaAccess.php

```
// include javascript for special functionality
?><script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var interval = null;
var data = $(this).attr('class').match(/({.*})/i);
data = (data && data[1]) ? data[1] : '' ;
data = eval("(" + (data.indexOf('{') < 0 ? '{' + data + '}' : data) + ")");
/* ]]> */
</script><?php
```

I want to submit this theme to the wordpress directory but they don't allow it with this error :/

Comment: *"eval() is not allowed"* Doesn't that explain why?

Comment: can you give us an example of what your class attribute would look like, and what you're doing with it after the eval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$.parseJSON(data.indexOf('{') < 0 ? '{' + data + '}' : data)`

*eval is evil*

Comment: Yours is the only on-topic answer. The newbie meme is unneeded though.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely shouldn't be using `eval` as it's potentially a serious security problem. See [this<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php), [this<sup>2</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482861/question-about-eval-in-php-5), [this<sup>3</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631246/risks-of-using-php-eval?rq=1), [this<sup>4</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499672/when-if-ever-is-eval-not-evil), [this<sup>5</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) or [this<sup>6</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797373/eval-whats-the-point).

Just rewrite your code in a way that eval is not needed.

Comment: Is there any way I can rewrite that line and maintain functionality of the class? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you had to use eval something went wrong. There should be no real situation to use eval that can't be properly implemented with best practice.

Comment: Its just the way the WPAlchemy Meta box class was coded.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: "ev"."al" as it is scanning your file for "eval". But wether the use of eval is good, is an other question.

Comment: This would probably also do the trick.