# Wp alchemy in theme, eval is not lallowed

Tags: php, wordpress, eval

Hi i find this warning with theme check in my Wordpress theme, i found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036246/eval-is-not-allowed) but not working for me, any ideas??

> WARNING: Found eval in the file inc/metaboxes/MediaAccess.php. `eval()` is not allowed..
>  
>   Line 375: `data = eval('(' + (data.indexOf('{') < 0 ? '{' + data + '}' : data) + ')');`

Comment: eval is disabled. do u really need it?

Comment: Hi, thank for the answer, i really don't but is a part of Wp-Alchemy class, i am using it to create some custom meta boxes in wordpress.

Comment: Can [it](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-meta-widget/) be a solution?

Comment: well thanks but not, what i really need is someone who can tell me how to traslate that eval expresion to $.parse.JSON valid expresion.

Comment: Post some code they are related to that error. Also dump the full code into paste bin then link it. Help us to help you

Comment: Finally i found it, changing eval() to window[]...yes!